# How to write to stdin when using popen prompts?

Tags: python

Iam spawning a process that prompts for a password, how do I feed the password ? 
I found the below solution in stackoverflow but doesnt seem to work all it prints is it prompts for password

```
class Actions():

    def console(self):
        return subprocess.Popen("myprogram",
                         stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                         stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                         stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                         shell=True,
                         close_fds=True)


    def ask_password(self, passw):
        delete = self.console().communicate("%s" % (passw))
        return(delete)


def main():
    password_string = "abc123"
    print Actions().password(password_string)
```

prints

('', 'Password: ')

```
--bash ---
>./myprogram
Password:abc123

"Welcome to console"
```

Comment: Are you sure your program reads passwords from standard input, rather than directly from the terminal?

Comment: not sure. the program iam trying is: https://linux.die.net/man/1/ipmitool